# remove jqueryui from dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my current project I'm using simple preloader for my report:

```
function hideLoading() {
    var selectedEffect = "scale";
    var options = { percent: 0 };
    $("div#loading").hide(selectedEffect, options, 1000, function () {
        $("div#fullsize").show();
    });
}
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(hideLoading, 1000);
});
```

This gives me nice hiding effect, but because of this I must add jQueryUI.
Normally it's OK, but in this project I'm not using anything from jQueryUI.
I would like to remove it and have nice looking hide effect.

I was trying to use jquery.easing (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) but without any luck.

This is sample to work with: http://jsbin.com/ukicac/1/

Comment: Use css as much as possible for your animations. Take a look as this simple example http://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html

Comment: @mguimard - will this work on ie8+?

Comment: It might work using prefixes but I'm not sure for IE8... Also, if you're targeting older browsers, you can implement fallback methods to handle your animations.

Comment: why do you need jqueryUI for this snippet? isnt it enough to use jquery.animate() and or jquery.fadeOut()?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to use JQueryUI for this. This can be done with JQuery easily.

Check the code here - http://jsbin.com/ukicac/8/

You can use this link for reference -http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Hope this helps. Cheers !

Comment: thanks for help! What I was using jQueryUI for was easing. I was using  scale as effect to hide my prealoader - it sort of shrinked to the center of screen and then disappeared. I would like to use easing to show/hide elements but without jQueryUI. I would appreciate simple example of using TweenJS (http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS) to do this